# cx_Oracle connection issue

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I've been aware of this oracle DB, tried several combinations of commands but still unable to connect. 
 below is my latest attempt to connect.

> ```
> ip = "173.37.65.217" #datamart
> port = '1810'
> SID = 'fntr3prd.cisco.com'  #'ARCHIVE_HC6_ARCH'#"fntr3prd"
> username = 'xx' # I don’t have permission to share
> password = 'xx' # I don’t have permission to share
> dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(ip, port, SID)
> con = cx_Oracle.connect(username,password,dsn_tns)
> cur = con.cursor()
>
> cur.execute("select * from  ARCHIVE_HC6_ARCH”)
> ```

The exception I get…

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/tlombard/Desktop/FY16Metrics/ppmArchive.py", line 12, in
>   
>       con = cx_Oracle.connect(username, password, dsn_tns) DatabaseError: ORA-12505: TNS:listener does not currently know of SID
>   given in connect descriptor

NOTE: as you can see below, I am able to connect to this database with sqlplus…

> SQL> DESC ARCHIVE_HC6_ARCH     Name                      Null?    Type 
>   ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------  ARCH_FISCAL_DT              NOT NULL DATE  HC                            NUMBER  DE_DT_YN                        VARCHAR2(30) 
>   RESOURCE_POSITION                 VARCHAR2(150)  CLIENT_FUNDED
>   VARCHAR2(200)  RESOURCE_NAME                      VARCHAR2(300) 
>   RESOURCE_DEPT_NAME                    VARCHAR2(150)  RESOURCE_DEPT_NO
>   NUMBER  RESOURCE_ID                       VARCHAR2(50)  RESOURCE_MANAGER
>   VARCHAR2(200)  RESOURCE_POOL                      VARCHAR2(255)  RESOURCE_ROLE
>   VARCHAR2(255)  RESOURCE_TITLE                     VARCHAR2(500) 
>   RESOURCE_TYPE                     VARCHAR2(7)  ROLE_CATEGORY                      VARCHAR2(255)
>   ROLE_GROUP                        VARCHAR2(255)  L0                           VARCHAR2(20)  L1
>   VARCHAR2(20)  L2                          VARCHAR2(20)  L3                            VARCHAR2(20) 
>   L4                            VARCHAR2(20)  UNNAMED                       VARCHAR2(30) 
>   WORK_COUNTRY                      VARCHAR2(100)  WORK_SITE                        VARCHAR2(300) 
>   MONTH_KEY                     NUMBER  MONTH                           VARCHAR2(50) 
>   QUARTER_KEY                       NUMBER  QUARTER_NAME                        VARCHAR2(50) 
>   YEAR_NAME                     VARCHAR2(50)  BPF                           VARCHAR2(255) 
>   PROJECT_PRIORITY                  VARCHAR2(100)  PROJECT_STATUS
>   VARCHAR2(200)  PRODUCT_FAMILY                     VARCHAR2(200)  PIN_AGGREGATED
>                     VARCHAR2(1000)  PROJECT_OS                      VARCHAR2(2000)  PLATFORM                        VARCHAR2(765)  PROJECT_CLASS                        VARCHAR2(100) 
>   PROJECT_ID                        VARCHAR2(300)  PROJECT_INITIATIVE
>   VARCHAR2(150)  PROJECT_LEAD                       VARCHAR2(150)  PROJECT_MGR
>   VARCHAR2(150)  PROJECT_CATEGORY                   VARCHAR2(300) 
>   PROJECT_NAME                      VARCHAR2(1500)  PROJECT_HEALTH
>   VARCHAR2(100)  PLANNED_RELEASE                    VARCHAR2(500) 
>   PROJECT_TECH_AREA                 VARCHAR2(150)  PROJECT_TYPE
>   VARCHAR2(150)  WORK_COUNTRY_SORT                  VARCHAR2(15) 
>   PROGRAM_NAME                      VARCHAR2(500)  YEAR_KEY                     NUMBER 
>   ARCH_FISCAL_MONTH                 VARCHAR2(100)  SOLUTION                     VARCHAR2(500)
>   PROJECT_ROLE_CATEGORY                 VARCHAR2(255)  RESORUCE_DEPT_FUNCTION
>   VARCHAR2(500)  RESOURCE_MANAGER_ID                    VARCHAR2(255) 
>   RESOURCE_ACTIVE                   VARCHAR2(50)  PROJECT_ACTIVE
>   VARCHAR2(100)  PROJECT_ORG                        VARCHAR2(255)  L5
>   VARCHAR2(20)  QUADRANT                        VARCHAR2(255)
>
> SQL>

Any ideas on what I should try next?

Comment: SID usually isn't the servers dns name, do you have some other way to access the database Toad perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that your using a service name instead of a sid

Try

```
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(ip, port, service_name=SID)
```

http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/module.html?highlight=makedsn#cx_Oracle.makedsn

Comment: Thank you #Diver !   you got me headed in the right direction...  to fix the issue I used:  dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(ip, port, service_name='fntr3prd.cisco.com')

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some other kind of access to the database try

```
SELECT sys_context('USERENV', 'SID') FROM DUAL;
```

and use that instead of

```
SID = 'fntr3prd.cisco.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the oracle client installed and LDAP configurations done for it?